# Create buttons in a loop and set array elements as title

Tags: loops, react-native, button

I want to create some buttons in a for loop and found the solution to push the buttons to an array and then use this array within my view. That works well so far.
But I can not manage to set the array elements as button titles:

```
render() {
  let numArray = this.props.numbers;

  if (numArray.length > 0) {
    var buttons = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++) {
      buttons.push(
        <Button
          title={numArray[i]}
          onPress={() => this.onButtonClick(i)}
        />
      );
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {buttons}
      </View>
    );
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's correct, and it should work! what error did you get?

Comment: Are you sure `<Button/>` knows how to handle the `title` input?

Comment: I found the error: My array contains numeric values and it seems that the button title does not accept numbers.